# How can I setup SFML 2.0 on my mac?

Tags: c++, macos, codeblocks, sfml

I've tried codeblocks, but nothing compiles. It stops with

```
-------------- Build: Debug in test2 ---------------

Linking console executable: bin/Debug/test2
ld: framework not found SFML
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I followed it. However, it gave me a lot of different errors for no apparent reason. I've tried multiple times with two different copies of sfml2 source. They were downloaded with about 4 months time inbetween. The oldest copy is the one i was using in visual studio 2010 on my pc. The other one is the one I am using now.

And also every time i restart the program all settings are lost. My next option is xcode3, but I can't find where to install the SFML files. A complete guide would really be the only thing I need. Codeblocks is prefered.

Answer (score 0):

Linker (ld) cannot find libraries
did you try: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/compile-with-cmake.php

Comment: Yes i did, however i don't really need it right now. I have other problems that come beforehand with the mac so I'll retry later on.

Answer (score 0):

Last I heard, [the OSX version was not up to date](http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=30086&sid=b59a2f69d09e049e4231cfbb0837e48b), but that was back in April, I don't know if they've been updated since then and I haven't tried to compile my own SFML project on my Mac in a while.

Comment: do you think you could give it a try, and if it works maybe send the compiled files to me? Or your instructions?

Comment: I don't have time at the moment, but I can try tonight after work or tomorrow. You might be better off asking for help over on the SFML forums.